# SpringSecurity: register filter only for specific URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, filter, spring-security

I am using a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter for my app which use jwt for authentication and everything works fine (first code snippet); what I want to do now is to add another filter only for a specific URL pattern but this filter is called in any case now (second code snippet). Somebody please explain me what am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
            .and().csrf().disable().httpBasic().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/configuration/**",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/",
                        "/refreshconfig",
                        "/launchGameForFun/**",
                        "/*.html",
                        "/*.gif",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()      
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint())
            .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new Slf4jMDCFilter(), JwtAuthorizationFilter.class)
                .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));
    }
```

adding this code above not work as expected:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
            .and().csrf().disable().httpBasic().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/configuration/**",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/",
                        "/refreshconfig",
                        "/launchGameForFun/**",
                        "/*.html",
                        "/*.gif",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()      
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint())
            .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new Slf4jMDCFilter(), JwtAuthorizationFilter.class)
                .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .antMatcher("/*/*wager")
                .addFilterAfter(new MultiReadServletFilter(), JwtAuthorizationFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(new XauthFilter(), MultiReadServletFilter.class);
    }
```

To be more clear: I want Slf4jMDCFilter and JwtAuthorizationFilter to be invoked for every URL (`/*/*wager` included) and MultiReadServletFilter and XauthFilter to be invoked only for `/*/*wager`. Obviously permitAll URLs are excluded in both cases.

Comment: try adding extra star in path like - /**/*wager

Comment: I tried, didn't work... XauthFilter and MultiReadServletFilter are always called

Comment: Alright, try splitting the HttpSecurity call for your wager URL. like this -  http.blablabla;        #till JwtAuthorizationFilter         then in new line -                                          
http.antMatcher("/*/*wager")
                .addFilterAfter(new MultiReadServletFilter(), JwtAuthorizationFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(new XauthFilter(), MultiReadServletFilter.class)

Comment: Thank you @ankidaemon I was able to achieve my goals mixing your first suggestion with declaring the 2 filters as FilterRegistrationBean with UrlPatterns